# Torus translation is ergodic if and only if the components of the translation vector are rationally independent.

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm reading Ergodic Theory and Differential Dynamics by Ricardo Mane. 
There is a theorem in the book that states the following:
If x $\in$ $R^n$, the translation L $_{\pi(x)}$: $T^n \rightarrow T^n$ is ergodic if and only if (k,x) $\notin$ Z for every k $\in Z^n$.

I was hoping someone could either give me or direct me to, a comprehensible proof of this result, as Mane's does not give very much explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this is not quite right: you need to exclude $k = 0$.

If $(k,x) \in \mathbb Z$ and $k \ne 0$, then $f(t) = \exp\left(2\pi i (k, t)\right)$ is invariant under $L_{\pi(x)}$ and is not a.e. constant.

Conversely, if $f \in L^1(\mathbb T^n)$ is invariant under $T_{\pi(x)}$,
look at the Fourier transform of $f$:
$\widehat{f}(k) = \int_{\mathbb T^m} \exp(-2\pi i (k,t)) f(t)\; dt$ (where $dt$ is normalized $m$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb T^m$).
Since $\widehat{L_{\pi(x)} f}(k) = \exp(2\pi i (k,x)) \widehat{f}(k)$, we must have $(k,x) \in \mathbb Z$
for any $k$ such that $\widehat{f}(k) \ne 0$.  If there are no such $k$ except $0$, then (by the fact that Fourier transform is one-to-one on 
$L^1$) $f$ is a.e. constant.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chris Please click on the checkmark if you are satisfied by the answer.