# Ergodic $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action

Tags: ergodic-theory

Recall that the action of a group $G$ on a probability space $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is said to be ergodic if, for all $A\in\mathscr{B}$,

$$ \forall g\in G\ \mu(A\Delta g\cdot A)=0 \implies \mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$$

I'm looking for an example of a $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action (say $T$) which is ergodic in the sense above, but such that $T^\vec{n}$ is non-ergodic (in the usual sense) for any $\vec{n}\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Intuitively, this would mean that the (almost) invariance under a single $T^{\vec{n}}$ is not sufficient to conclude that the set has null or total measure. However, I don't see how to construct such an action. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take $X = \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ as the standard $2$-torus with Lebesgue measure, and the action $(a,b) \cdot (x,y) = (x+av, y+bw)$, where $v$ and $w$ are irrational.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after thinking about it for awhile, I think I came up with a proof, but it relies heavily on the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure, while it is my understanding that it holds in general that given two ergodic $\mathbb{Z}$ actions, the induced $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is also ergodic. By any chance, would you happen to have a reference for this?

Comment: I agree with this answer if $(v,w,1)$ are rationally dependent (for example if $v=w$ is an irrational number), but otherwise the action of $(1,1)$ is ergodic.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266904/torus-translation-is-ergodic-if-and-only-if-the-components-of-the-translation-ve